# Is integer a secondary redis data type?

Tags: redis

I am learning redis and just saw this talk from redis lab. One thing puzzled me is, at 8'34'' he listed redis data types as primary and secondary, here is the [direct link](https://youtu.be/qHkXVY2LpwU?t=514), and integer is a secondary data type. Hmm, how come integer is secondary? Does that mean I need to use Redis Stack in order to store integer value to database? This does not look right to me.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, Redis stores data in different ways internally, including 64 bit integers.
From the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/object-encoding/):

> Redis objects can be encoded in different ways:
>
> **Strings** can be encoded as:
>
> - raw, normal string encoding.
> - int, strings representing integers in a 64-bit signed interval, encoded  in this way to save space.
> - embstr, an
>   embedded string, which is an object where the internal simple dynamic
>   string, sds, is an unmodifiable string allocated in the same chuck as
>   the object itself. embstr can be strings with lengths up to the
>   hardcoded limit of OBJ_ENCODING_EMBSTR_SIZE_LIMIT or 44 bytes.
>
> **Lists**
> can be encoded as ziplist or linkedlist. The ziplist is the special
> representation that is used to save space for small lists.
>
> **Sets** can be encoded as intset or hashtable. The intset is a special
> encoding used for small sets composed solely of integers.
>
> **Hashes** can be encoded as ziplist or hashtable. The ziplist is a
> special encoding used for small hashes.
>
> **Sorted Sets** can be encoded as ziplist or skiplist format. As for the
> List type small sorted sets can be specially encoded using ziplist,
> while the skiplist encoding is the one that works with sorted sets of
> any size.
>
> All the specially encoded types are automatically converted to the
> general type once you perform an operation that makes it impossible
> for Redis to retain the space saving encoding.

To inspect which encoding Redis is using for a given key, one can use the [`OBJECT ENCODING` command](https://redis.io/commands/object-encoding/).